# How to create Cordova project?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I created a JS / HTML Cordova project with command

```
$ create cordova example
```

Then I saw the code below in the file `example/www/js/index.js`:

[image]

but in this picture of cordova/events website:

[image]

I saw another code in training that differed from my js. I copied this js code to instead of my `index.js`, but did not get any results.

Why is there a difference between my code and website cordova?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when create cordova project as blank, some code will be generated automatically like you mentioned.

```
create cordova example
```

cordova/events website's code is another example.
you should use one of them, can't use both at the same time because somethings are same function.